# Convert DATETIME in millisecond

Tags: time, conversion, date

I have the Date Time format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD` like `2014-11-03T18:54:40.533+05:33333`
i have to convert it into milliseconds.
i use `date -d "$time" +%s0000` but getting error `invalid date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something's wrong with your Timezone definition. It should `+05:30` (assuming IST), not `+05:33333`:

```
$ date -d "2014-11-03T18:54:40.533+05:30" +%s0000   
14150210800000
```

Comment: ya its working,thanks.Actually in my file first entry is wrong and remaining is according to IST.